# timer that starts on button click

Tags: android, xamarin

so what I am trying to accomplish is a timer I am using xamarin in visual studio and its aimed for android.I have a TextView in the xaml called txtStopwatch which I want to start counting the second the first button is clicked.This timer and the end button are hidden until thestart button is hit.

```
        if (btnStart.Click == true)

        {

            btnStart.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            btnEnd.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            Stopwatch.Start() = txtStopwatch.Text;
        }

        else

        {

            btnStart.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            btnEnd.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            Stopwatch.Start();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing Stopwatch is an instance of Stopwatch (very horrible naming, never use the class type name for an instance):

```
    if (btnStart.Click == true)
    {

        btnStart.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        btnEnd.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        Stopwatch.Start();
    }
    else
    {

        btnStart.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        btnEnd.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        Stopwatch.Stop();
        txtStopwatch.Text = Stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
    }
```